# Google Prediction API vs Graph Databases for Generated Recommendations?

Tags: google-analytics, recommendation-engine, graph-databases, google-prediction

(I admit I am no expert in graph databases or NoSQL, having only used it for a few hobby projects so far.)

I've been using technologies like InfiniteGraph and Stig for recommendations - these are graph databases that supposedly are optimized for tasks like this. It looks like the new Google Predictions API is capable of serving the same purpose -- given a data set and a user's actual likes as a subset, be able to predict what the user might actually like.

Is there a sure-metric to compare Google Predictions with other graph-based databases?

Comment: One obvious difference is that Google Predictions is a cloud based service while others are not. Haven't seen any comparison thus far though.

Comment: You can train the algorithms with a subset of your data and test them with the remainder. Also, I didn't think the graph databases came with recommendation algorithms. Only they provide a mechanism for implementing your own. Unless you're talking about this (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-similar-favorites.html), which is just a trivial example, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The prediction is quite obvious and right. But as per my knowledge, Google Prediction API uses Page ranking mechanism; not sure about graph database. Unlike Facebook, Google might using GDB for Google+, but in one of official neo4j blog they haven't mentioned anything about Google.